# Reserving seats system in react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to make a reserving seats for my airline website. I have done a reserve seats button, when pressed, a page pops up, where it has the array of current available seats and checkboxes besides it in-order to choose your seats. All of these are going fine, but the thing is that when I checkboxes or remove the checkboxes, I need to save the values that I've checked in another array to send them back to the backend and in the backend, I am going to compare it to the previous array and remove the seats that have been chosen.

```
function Row(props){

const [AvailableFSeats, setfs] = useState();
  const [fList,setfList]= useState([]);
  const checkf= [];
 useEffect(() => {
    setfList(props.row.AvailableFSeats);
  },[])

const handleChange = (event) => {
    setState({
      ...state,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.checked,
    });

//checkf should be the array that contains the chosen seats in the current action.
    if(event.target.name==="AvailableFSeats"&&event.target.checked===true){
      checkf.push(event.target.label);}
}
  const {AvailableFFSeats, AvailableEESeats, AvailableBBSeats} = state;

return(
 <Box sx={{ display: 'flex' }}>
  <FormControl sx={{ m: 3 }} component="fieldset" variant="standard">
    <FormLabel component="legend">First Class Seats</FormLabel>
    <FormGroup>
          {fList.map(AvailableFSeats => (
            <FormControlLabel
            control={
              <Checkbox checked={AvailableFFSeats} onChange={handleChange} name="AvailableFSeats" />
            }
            label={AvailableFSeats}
          />)
          )}
          </FormGroup>
  </FormControl>
</Box>
)

}
```

Comment: What do you need help with? Arrays? The node bacend? Or mongo?

Comment: Arrays and node backend @christianeide